# Code for Urn (containing colored balls) generator?

Tags: technology-in-education, online-instruction, probability

I am interested in code that generates an urn with various colored balls for an economics experiment. I came across this thread: [Urn (containing colored balls) generator?](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/14302/urn-containing-colored-balls-generator)

However, the server that the code was on has been taken down, and I can't seem to find a way to use this site to contact the user that originally coded it.

Are there ways to either (a) contact the user who wrote the code or (b) see if code like this has been done in the past?

Thanks,
Keaton

Comment: Hi, I do not think your question is on topic here. Please see: https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic
Maybe ask around on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: Thanks for reminding me. The server went down when the OVH Strassbourg datacenter caught fire. I uploaded the script, the link is working again.